# git submodule update --init --recursive is not cloning submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to clone the [FireChip](https://github.com/firesim/firechip) repository.
The get started say to run the following commands to start off with

```
git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/project-template.git
cd project-template
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

so when i  run `git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/project-template.git`  i get

```
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test$ git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/project-template.git
Cloning into 'project-template'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 81, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
remote: Total 17234 (delta 22), reused 50 (delta 11), pack-reused 17153
Receiving objects: 100% (17234/17234), 6.54 MiB | 5.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9476/9476), done.
```

When i run  `git submodule update --init --recursive`in it. It ends up showing

```
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test/project-template$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'fpga/fpga-shells' (https://github.com/sifive/fpga-shells.git) registered for path 'fpga/fpga-shells'
Submodule 'generators/boom' (https://github.com/riscv-boom/riscv-boom.git) registered for path 'generators/boom'
Submodule 'generators/cva6' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/cva6-wrapper.git) registered for path 'generators/cva6'
Submodule 'generators/gemmini' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/gemmini) registered for path 'generators/gemmini'
Submodule 'generators/hwacha' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/hwacha.git) registered for path 'generators/hwacha'
Submodule 'generators/icenet' (https://github.com/firesim/icenet.git) registered for path 'generators/icenet'
Submodule 'generators/nvdla' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/nvdla-wrapper.git) registered for path 'generators/nvdla'
Submodule 'generators/riscv-sodor' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-sodor.git) registered for path 'generators/riscv-sodor'
Submodule 'rocket-chip' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip.git) registered for path 'generators/rocket-chip'
Submodule 'generators/sha3' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/sha3.git) registered for path 'generators/sha3'
Submodule 'generators/sifive-blocks' (https://github.com/sifive/sifive-blocks.git) registered for path 'generators/sifive-blocks'
Submodule 'generators/block-inclusivecache-sifive' (https://github.com/sifive/block-inclusivecache-sifive.git) registered for path 'generators/sifive-cache'
Submodule 'testchipip' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/testchipip.git) registered for path 'generators/testchipip'
Submodule 'sims/firesim' (https://github.com/firesim/firesim.git) registered for path 'sims/firesim'
Submodule 'software/coremark' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/coremark-workload.git) registered for path 'software/coremark'
Submodule 'software/firemarshal' (https://github.com/firesim/FireMarshal.git) registered for path 'software/firemarshal'
Submodule 'software/nvdla-workload' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/nvdla-workload.git) registered for path 'software/nvdla-workload'
Submodule 'software/spec2017' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/spec2017-workload.git) registered for path 'software/spec2017'
Submodule 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/esp-gnu-toolchain.git) registered for path 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain'
Submodule 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-isa-sim' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/esp-isa-sim.git) registered for path 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-isa-sim'
Submodule 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-pk' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-pk.git) registered for path 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-pk'
Submodule 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-tests' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/esp-tests.git) registered for path 'toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-tests'
Submodule 'toolchains/libgloss' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/libgloss-htif.git) registered for path 'toolchains/libgloss'
Submodule 'toolchains/qemu' (https://github.com/qemu/qemu.git) registered for path 'toolchains/qemu'
Submodule 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain.git) registered for path 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain'
Submodule 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain-prebuilt' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard-toolchain-prebuilt.git) registered for path 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain-prebuilt'
Submodule 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-isa-sim' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim.git) registered for path 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-isa-sim'
Submodule 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-openocd' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-openocd.git) registered for path 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-openocd'
Submodule 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-pk' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-pk.git) registered for path 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-pk'
Submodule 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-tests' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests.git) registered for path 'toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-tests'
Submodule 'tools/DRAMSim2' (https://github.com/firesim/DRAMSim2.git) registered for path 'tools/DRAMSim2'
Submodule 'tools/axe' (https://github.com/CTSRD-CHERI/axe.git) registered for path 'tools/axe'
Submodule 'barstools' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/barstools.git) registered for path 'tools/barstools'
Submodule 'tools/chisel-testers' (https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-testers.git) registered for path 'tools/chisel-testers'
Submodule 'tools/chisel3' (https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3.git) registered for path 'tools/chisel3'
Submodule 'tools/dromajo/dromajo-src' (https://github.com/riscv-boom/dromajo.git) registered for path 'tools/dromajo/dromajo-src'
Submodule 'tools/dsptools' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/dsptools.git) registered for path 'tools/dsptools'
Submodule 'tools/firrtl' (https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl) registered for path 'tools/firrtl'
Submodule 'tools/firrtl-interpreter' (https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl-interpreter.git) registered for path 'tools/firrtl-interpreter'
Submodule 'tools/torture' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-torture.git) registered for path 'tools/torture'
Submodule 'tools/treadle' (https://github.com/freechipsproject/treadle.git) registered for path 'tools/treadle'
Submodule 'vlsi/hammer' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/hammer.git) registered for path 'vlsi/hammer'
Submodule 'vlsi/hammer-cadence-plugins' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/hammer-cadence-plugins.git) registered for path 'vlsi/hammer-cadence-plugins'
Submodule 'vlsi/hammer-mentor-plugins' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/hammer-mentor-plugins.git) registered for path 'vlsi/hammer-mentor-plugins'
Submodule 'vlsi/hammer-synopsys-plugins' (https://github.com/ucb-bar/hammer-synopsys-plugins.git) registered for path 'vlsi/hammer-synopsys-plugins'
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/fpga/fpga-shells'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/boom'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/cva6'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/gemmini'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/hwacha'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/icenet'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/nvdla'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/riscv-sodor'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/rocket-chip'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/sha3'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/sifive-blocks'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/sifive-cache'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/generators/testchipip'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/sims/firesim'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/software/coremark'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/software/firemarshal'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/software/nvdla-workload'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/software/spec2017'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-isa-sim'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-pk'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/esp-tools/riscv-tests'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/libgloss'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/qemu'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain-prebuilt'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-isa-sim'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-openocd'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-pk'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-tests'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/DRAMSim2'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/axe'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/barstools'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/chisel-testers'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/chisel3'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/dromajo/dromajo-src'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/dsptools'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/firrtl'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/firrtl-interpreter'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/torture'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/tools/treadle'...
Cloning into '/home/talmadage/test/project-template/vlsi/hammer'...
```

But it all the submodule folders after the operation is done are empty

```
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test/project-template$ ls
build.sbt  CHANGELOG.md  common.mk  CONTRIBUTING.md  docs  fpga  generators  LICENSE  LICENSE.SiFive  project  README.md  scripts  sims  software  tests  toolchains  tools  variables.mk  vcs.mk  vlsi
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test/project-template$ cd generators
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test/project-template/generators$ ls
boom  chipyard  cva6  firechip  gemmini  hwacha  icenet  nvdla  riscv-sodor  rocket-chip  sha3  sifive-blocks  sifive-cache  testchipip  tracegen  utilities
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test/project-template/generators$ cd boom
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test/project-template/generators/boom$ ls
talmadage@talmadage-Inspiron-5567:~/test/project-template/generators/boom$
```

This issue happens on windows 10 as well as ubuntu 20.04 and deepin 15.11

Comment: maybe giving some context on you code tree could be useful... if git says it clones something, it is very likely that something was cloned, but maybe you are not looking in the right place or something...

Comment: edited it to add more info

Comment: are you sure a clone does not fail? I'm being asked for a password and if I do not give it, the update fails (all files are not checked-out)

Comment: try `git submodule update --init --recursive generators/`

Comment: Ahh makes sense i thought that it would show the other submodules when the proprietary modules were not accessible

Comment: Hello! How about `git submodule foreach git submodule update --init --recursive` this should enter any of submodule and get all submodules from there and so on.